# Multiple ConditionalOnClass

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to create a @ConditionalOnClass that checks for two classes at the same time.
I know the annotation is non-repeatable, but I would want to know if it is possible.

Maybe creating a custom condition?

I have tried putting two ConditionalOnClass and creating a custom Condition but I don't know how.

Comment: `@ConditionalOnClass` annotation has 2 properties. `name` of type String array and `value` of type Class array. So, you can add more classes. See javadoc https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnClass.html

Comment: What is the expected result? Are both classes required? If this is the case: you know that [`ConditionalOnClass`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnClass.html#value()) allows you to specify multiple classes that must be present?

Comment: Now if only `value` would accept an array... Yu can pass multiple classes as it does accept an array.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, you can just put an array of names:

@ConditionalOnClass(name =  {"org.springframework.Class1", "org.springframework.Class2" })